# How can a Leiningen plugin implement profile-like functionality for a plugin-specific project section?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to implement a Leiningen plugin configured using a dedicated project sub-map. The latter contains a "profiles" section containing plugin-specific profiles and the plugin's code is trying to merge one of them into the main plugin sub-map through the same merging logic Leiningen profiles use.

I first tried to implement this by injecting corresponding top-level Leiningen profiles into the project map and then by calling `merge-profiles` but Leiningen seems not to find such injected profiles (I tried by using middleware code as well with no outcome difference). By debugging `leiningen.core.project` I realised Leiningen looks up available profiles in project metadata, which doesn't contain the injected profiles.

Is there a way to implement such a logic easily and without fiddling with Leiningen's internals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PLUGINS.md#evaluating-in-project-context `merge-profiles` should be passed the project and an array of the profile *maps*. I was passing in an array of *profile names* instead, which seems to work anyway indeed but only for profiles defined in the original project source file.